# Python: Remove duplicates from DataFrame based on another column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have the following table with fictive data:

[image]

I want to remove any duplicate rows and keep only the row which contains a positive value in "Won Turnover". Hence, the two rows marked with red should be removed in this case

Moreover, if there are duplicate rows with only Lost Turnover, then the row with the highest turnover should be kept (The bottom two rows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can do it:

```
df.sort_values(['Won Turnover', 'Lost Turnover'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Supplier')
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the fact that there may not be any Won Turnover and yes multiple Lost Turnover.

Comment: @FrancoPiccolo I think this edit should cover all the cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution gave me the right answer. However, I had to replace 'Supplier' with 'Matching Key' in the drop_duplicates statement

Answer (score 0):

First test `Won Turnover` if only missing value per groups with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) and test only `max` value per `Lost Turnover`. Chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` and add new condition for return all not missing rows per `Won Turnover` with `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
m1 = (df.assign(new = df['Won Turnover'].isna())
        .groupby(['Date','Supplier','Customer'])['new'].transform('all'))
m2 = (df.groupby(['Date','Supplier','Customer'])['Lost Turnover'].transform('max')
        .eq(df['Lost Turnover']))
df = df[(m1 & m2) | df['Won Turnover'].notna()]
print (df)

         Date Supplier   Customer  Won Turnover  Lost Turnover
1  25.06.2019     Nike      Pepsi       25000.0            NaN
2  25.06.2019     Nike  McDonalds       10000.0            NaN
3  25.06.2019   Adidas  Coca Cola       12000.0            NaN
5  25.06.2019   Adidas  McDonalds       35000.0            NaN
6  25.06.2019   Adidas      Pepsi           NaN        15000.0
```